# Fetch root entity with their junction tables and include their principal tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Test entity:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        PupilsTests = new HashSet<PupilTest>();
        TestTypeTests = new HashSet<TestTypeTest>();
        SchoolclassTests = new HashSet<SchoolclassTest>();
        SubjectTests = new HashSet<SubjectTest>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public ISet<PupilTest> PupilsTests { get; set; }
    public ISet<TestTypeTest> TestTypeTests { get; set; }
    public ISet<SchoolclassTest> SchoolclassTests { get; set; }
    public ISet<SubjectTest> SubjectTests { get; set; }

    public GradingKey ScoreGradeKey { get; set; }
    public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }

}
```

I need to fetch all Test entities filtered by schoolyearId including the **junction tables SchoolclassTests, SubjectTests, TestTypeTests.**

But with these junction tables I also have to include their **principal tables** **Schoolclass, Subject, TestType**.

This is what I tried:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Test>> GetTestsAsync(int schoolyearId)
{
return await context.Tests.Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
                          .Include(t => t.SchoolclassTests)
                          .Include(t => t.SubjectTests)
                          .Include(t => t.TestTypeTests)
                          // How to include all 3 Principal tables? ThenInclude does not workk
                          // over all the 3...
                          .ToListAsync();
}
```

Whatever combinations I try for .Include or ThenInclude I never get all 3 principal tables with the junction tables in ONE query.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Select` method, you can include the principal tables of your join tables:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Test>> GetTestsAsync(int schoolyearId)
{
    return await context.Tests.Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
            .Include(t => t.SchoolclassTests.Select(s => s.Schoolclass))
            .Include(t => t.SubjectTests.Select(s => s.Subject))
            .Include(t => t.TestTypeTests.Select(t => t.TestType))                
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Funny... I did that on the ThenInclude and did not thought of using it on   the Include... a midnight programmer disease ;-)

Comment: `Select` replaced with `ThenInclude` in EF Core.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour literally done that and it does not work/compile, please paste code sample in a solution :-)